# Graph produced from Prometheus time series jumps between different shapes

Tags: graph, monitoring, grafana, prometheus

I use Prometheus 2.0.0-beta.2 and Grafana to view the graph for a simple gauge time series of the form `mytimeseries{attr="val"}`. Its range comprises the last 6 hours and it is refreshed every 30 seconds.

What currently happens is that the graph's shape jumps between different forms for subsequent refreshes in an approx. cycle. Here are a few of of these shapes:

[image]

[image]

[image]

How can this ever happen? I suspect it's because the time series spikes at a few points (e.g. to approx. 25 K at approx. 10:30) and that these values are included in the graph in some instances but not others perhaps due to the  period shown by Grafana shifting at "odd" offsets relative to new recorded metrics arriving in Prometheus.

In any case, this makes the output hard to read and the current graph almost useless for monitoring. I am wondering if this is an instance of a more general, perhaps known problem and if so, what is the best way to overcome it so that the same graph shifts from right to left but does not otherwise change its shape unexpectedly.

**UPDATE** [This](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/2364) discussion seems to concern a similar problem with hint at a similar suspected cause. My time series measures octets received per second (as reported by an operating system tool), and although I control the  exporter that feeds it into Prometheus, it's not unclear to me how it could be fed into a counter (instead of a gauge), so the suggested solution does not readily apply.

Comment: Have you tried to set query resolution to `1/1` in Graph's Metrics settings?

Comment: @YooryN. Yes, but this had no effect on the indicated problem. Also setting min [step](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/2564) to a very small value (e.g. `1s`, perhaps reliably a common denominator of all the scraping intervals involved) currently looks more promising. The exact reason escapes me, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an aliasing problem. Given you only have a gauge to work with, I'd suggest using `avg_over_time` or `max_over_time` to avoid losing data.

I'd also suggest seeing if the node exporter exposes this metric, as that'll be as a counter.

Comment: So which specific expression should I try instead of `mytimeseries{attr="val"}` to display the same graph without an aliasing problem? And I don't understand your 2nd sentence.